# How to access file geodatabase in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase, windows

How does one access data from an Esri file geodatabase in Quantum GIS?

I've seen snippets of conversation that indicate it's possible with qgis 1.7+ and gdal 1.9+ but no clear recipe.

I recognize that in a few months or a year this will likely be a non question ("just click [add data] button"), but today, I'm stumped. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) and install the `gdal-filegdb` package. I compiled and uploaded the binaries to include them as part of the distribution.

[File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis) has a step by step recipe.

Comment: are you sure? the [package listing](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/versions.html) only shows gdal-filegdb v1.8, and doesn't seem to change anything for me. In any case I'll follow up in the o4w mailing list as this is probably more relevant there.

Comment: ...answer now accepted, as I determined the problems I was experiencing had to do with our unsupported "custom" coordinate system (see comments on linked step-by-step recipe). Thanks for contributing the driver Ragi!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it you need GDAL 1.9 but you need to compile it for Windows

gdal/ogr [1.9]

copy compiled files to

\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\bin\FileGDBAPI.dll

\Quantum GIS Wroclaw \bin\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730130246/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-dev.zip)

To add the File Geodatabase to QGIS
Add vector layer, select the Directory radio button in the file
browser & select a filename.gdb directory

or wait for the next version of QGIS 1.7.5?

Comment: no, it will work both on windows and linux (and whatever). You have to download the File GDB Esri API and compild GDAL linking it. Then compile QGIS ;)