# Working with File Geodatabase in QGIS for MAC OSX?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, mac

I understand there are programs like OSGeo4W that allow windows users to work with Esri File Geodatabases, but is there something similar for Mac OSX 10.6?

Comment: You are going to need to give us more info. What steps have you followed?

Answer (score 18):

OSGeo4W is, well, OSGeo "for Windows", so it is not what you are looking for.

I have not done it myself, but other people have, so I know it works.

I would recommend you

1. get the [KyngChaos binaries for QGIS](https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/)
2. compile the OGR FileGDB driver (which will produce a "dylib" file on the Mac)
3. drop the dylib on the plugins directory of GDAL on the Mac. I believe this directory is */Library/Application Support/GDAL/PlugIns/$(GDALVER)* [according to the Kyngchaos documentation (very last line)](https://www.kyngchaos.com/2008/01/02/gdal-1-5-0-1/).

For #2, you will need to [download the exact version of GDAL](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) that is used by the Kyngchaos build you have. [Instructions on how to create the dylib for filegdb can be found on the net](https://gist.github.com/zhm/2005158#comments).

I realize this is not for the faint of heart, it would be nice if somebody created a brew recipe for this. hint hint, anyone?

**Update**

There is a much easier way now using Homebrew:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. Go to the [ESRI site and download the FileGDB API for Mac](http://resources.arcgis.com/node/agreement/3193). After extracting, you will notice that there is a **lib** folder and an **include** folder.
3. Copy the contents of the **include** folder to **/usr/local/include** and the **lib** folder to **/usr/local/lib** (this is basically "installing" the FileGDB API in your system)
4. Install gdal using brew (pass the with-unsupported flag).

   brew install gdal --with-unsupported

That's it!

Optionally, if you want QGIS, install it using this [Homebrew Science recipe](https://web.archive.org/web/20200301104238/https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science).

Comment: the link to the arcgis website somehow requires login and password...

Comment: @donschoe that is ESRI's requirement. You can create an ESRI global account in the link below the login page - it is free

Comment: You can now download the FGDB API without logging in from this page: http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3

Comment: @scw that link requires me to log in after choosing my package.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but I had to install the kyngchaos FGDB plugin from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete.

Answer (score 4):

From your problem description, it seems ok to just get the data out somehow.

Try [GDB Flee](https://github.com/mweisman/gdbflee), an online tool to convert GDBs into open formats.

Comment: The GDB github link has turned to be an invalid one : 503 Service Error. Could you update it?

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll have to [compile GDAL with ESRI FileGDB support](https://gist.github.com/2005158). Once you've done that, you can then use this build of GDAL in a KyngChaos build of QGIS. On your terminal:

```
# save your current GDAL so you can put it back if you want
cp /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/GDAL /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/GDAL_orig

# symlink the custom GDAL build to the place QGIS looks
rm /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/GDAL
ln -s ~/local/lib/libgdal.dylib /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/GDAL
```

Thanks to @Ragi for the instructions to the [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/2005158).

Answer (score 1):

OSGeo4W reads GDBs using [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) which you can install on OS X via [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [Kygchaos's binary distribution](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software%3aframeworks#gdal_complete).

Answer (score 1):

.gdb is the proprietary format for ESRI's geodatabases. For more information on how to access gdb look here

[File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis)

Comment: I guess I should of also added that I'm using a MAC so this plug-in won't work for me. Also, if you look at the data I listed above, a WHOLE bunch of files download. I'm not even sure what I'm looking at. Which one is the right one?

Comment: gdb is a geo-database. ESRI is using a modified ms-access schema to store and validate geographic data. The bunch of data (I assume inside a folder that ends in .gdb) is just tables that mean to work together somehow. Since your software cannot handle the file/folder you see all those files.

Comment: NYC open data and they using closed formats... It's open only for those who can buy arcgis

Comment: RATS! It can't be easy all the time!

Comment: @MikeGuillen Please indicate your OS next time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got file geodatabases working on QGIS for Mac. Using the instructions on the readme file of Kyngchaos FileGDB plugin:

download and install FileGDB plugin from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete

download and unzip fileGDB API from resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api

Move the 2 .dylib files from the lib folder of the fileGDB API to the folder /Library/Application Support/GDAL/1.9/Libraries

start QGIS, add vector layer, select the source type as directory and ESRI FileGDB should appear right away.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I followed the instructions but ESRI FileGDB doesn't show up. I'm using Mac OS 10.8. I've tried with GDAL v1.9 and v1.10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're adding a directory instead of a file? In order to add a gdb you need to choose "directory" when selecting the type of vector file to be added.