# Opening GDB files using QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get “.GDB” Esri File Geodatabase in Qgis for MAC OSX 10.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-for-mac-osx-10-6)

I have some data located here: https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Facilities-and-Structures/Building-Footprints/xe92-xce7

I'm trying to import this data into QGIS and am unable. I'm a novice at this. Ultimately, I'm trying to upload it to indiemapper.