# Opening personal geodatabase in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mac, personal-geodatabase

I am trying to use an ArcGIS (10.2) personal database MDB as a container for data to pass to a QGIS user. I formerly used QGIS 1.8 for Mac OSX, and after some fiddling around, I was able to open a personal geodatabase and load one or more features from it.

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.0 and upon trying to check my MDB test file before sending to my colleague, I am unable to load the geodatabase. In fact, personal geodatabase as a file type no longer appears in the available types QGIS is prepared to open in the File Type drop down box in the load vector data operation.

Is there some setting I need to tweak or an additional plugin I need to install in order to regain this functionality?

Comment: I see someone else has asked a similar question: Personal Geodatabase not recognized as valid datasource in the last QGIS Windows Weekly build (64 bits). I am using Mac OS X Mtn Lion and installed the 64-bit build.

Comment: if ogrinfo says it can read it, then you shouldn't have any problems. what `orginfo /path/to/db.mdb` says?

Comment: Hm. When I try run ogrinfo from a command line, it tells me command not found.

Comment: That's strange. I thought qgis comes along with ogr/gdal (since most of the times qgis wraps around the functionality of those libraries). Maybe i am mistaken and thats not the case anymore? On a side note, I miss spelled the command. The correct command is `ogrinfo`

Comment: It is possible that it requires a full path to the command file, "orginfo"? I installed everything on the kyngChaos download page. Maybe I need to do a shutdown & restart?

Comment: `oGrinfo` not `oRginfo`

Comment: :) Yes, I caught that and typed it correctly at the command line. Perhaps I am missing some critical installation? I thought the KyngChaos site had a complete GDAL installation, as well as NUMPY. Thank you for your patience on this.

Comment: I re-installed the entire package from scratch, and it still does not contain any ability to open ESRI Personal Geodatabases. I have searched for "ogrinfo" in my Mac, and so far as I can see, it does not exist on my system. I believe I have installed everything from the KyngChaos site, but the lack of any "ESRI Personal Geodatabase" option in the dropdown list suggests there is a significant missing module or something. Any ideas, folks? nickves has been helping me so far, but I am not having any success. Should I uninstall QGIS 2.0 and re-install QGIS 1.8?

Comment: My simple reply is that I inherited a huge inventory of data already compiled to personal geodatabase format. I need to make it available to my colleague in a format he can access. I rather suspect this means converting several hundreds of Gb of data back out to say, shapefiles, or KMLs.

The file format itself has limitations but also advantages. Process-wise, for us it is simpler if the software can simply read the data and then move it into a POSTGIS database afterward. 

In my case, I don't have a choice. I have hundreds of Gb already in MDB format, and not much time to make it accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Try 32-bit version - on Windows it works.

Comment: 32 bit version of QGIS?

Comment: Yes, there is a 32- and 64-bit version of QGIS on Windows, via [the OSGeo4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). The 64-bit version is a recent addition.

Comment: Yes, try install 32bit QGIS. I have installed 64bit QGIS on 64bit W7 and there was a problem. After reinstallation of 32bit QGIS on 64bit W7 everything is okay.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the Java-based MDB driver is included in the most recent [GDAL-Complete framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks). Please file a request with kyngchaos.com, though understand there may be issues with creating a one-size-fits-all package installer (see JAVA note below). IMHO, the Java-based MDB driver is the only reliable means of reading MDB files for Mac OS X, as of now, since the [PGeo and related Geomedia drivers](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html) fail to function anymore via ODBC.

I have a [patch for compiling-in the Java-based MDB driver for Mac that was applied to the GDAL 2.0 branch](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5267), but not to the upcoming 1.10.2. There is also a [homebrew pull request](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/23229). Nether of those will help a current Kyngchaos.com install to support MDB, though.

In the meantime, if you don't mind trying it yourself, you can attempt to build a shared plugin for GDAL 1.10, install it, and see if it works with your data source:

1. Ensure you have XCode and/or its command line tools installed.
2. Download [the GDAL source](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) (MUST match same GDAL version as Kyngchaos.com's) and un-archive to folder, then enter and configure the build for basic defines for your OS (no other options necessary):

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/gdal-1.10.1
   $ ./configure
   ```
3. Build shared plugin:

   ```
   # make directory for build output
   $ mkdir ogr_plugins

   # compile shared plugin (multi-line, single command)
   $ g++ -Wall -g ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb/ogr*.c* -shared -o ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib \
     -Iport -Igcore -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb \
     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers \
     -framework GDAL -framework JavaVM

   # fix lib id
   $ install_name_tool -id ogr_MDB.dylib ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib

   # copy plugin to known GDAL_DRIVER_PATH (sudo needed)
   $ sudo cp -f ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib /Library/Application\ Support/GDAL/1.10/PlugIns/
   ```
4. Install necessary *.jar support files (or the driver will not work at all). See [the MDB driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mdb.html), under *How to run the MDB driver (on Linux)* for details. Ignore step #1 and for step #3 substitute `/Library/Java/Extensions` for `lib/ext`. I used the noted downloads from the related *mdb-sqlite* project on that page, [browse source here](https://code.google.com/p/mdb-sqlite/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flib).
5. Verify plugin:

   ```
   $ cd /Library/Application\ Support/GDAL/1.10/PlugIns
   $ otool -L ogr_MDB.dylib
   ogr_MDB.dylib:
       ogr_MDB.dylib (...)
       /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/GDAL (...)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/JavaVM (...)
       /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (...)
       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (...)

   $ ogrinfo --formats | grep 'MDB'
   -> "MDB" (readonly)
   ```
6. Launch QGIS and verify plugin loading in PyQGIS console:

   ```
   from osgeo import ogr
   sorted([ogr.GetDriver(drv).name for drv in range(0,ogr.GetDriverCount())])
   ```
7. You should be able to load a MDB data source via `Add Vector Layer > File > Browse`, or try drag/drop of *.mdb file. Note, *.mdb files do not yet show up in the browser panel.

If you have MDB driver support in GDAL, but for whatever reason QGIS does not load the file, or because the loading in QGIS is very slow, try using the `ogr2ogr` utility to convert the layers to a more useable format.

**IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT JAVA**: The above plugin build command assumes an Apple-supported install of Java 1.6.x. However, since Apple has dropped support for native Java installs, and now (since 10.8) recommends users download and install the latest Java from Oracle, adjust the commands to **accommodate an Oracle install**:

- (*supplement to #1 above*) Update Java Home path link. If Oracle Java has been installed, this is not updated and may point to old Apple-supported Home (i.e. now a broken symbolic link).

  ```
  $ cd /Library/Java
  $ sudo rm Home
  $ sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home) .
  ```

  **Note**: if you update your Java version, you will probably have to update this symbolic link as well, and maybe recompile the shared plugin, if you want to use the new Java version.
- (*replaces #3 above*) Build shared plugin:

  ```
  # make directory for build output
  $ mkdir ogr_plugins

  # compile shared plugin (multi-line, single command)
  $ g++ -Wall -g ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb/ogr*.c* -shared -o ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib \
    -Iport -Igcore -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb \
    -I/Library/Java/Home/include -I/Library/Java/Home/include/darwin \
    -L/Library/Java/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -framework GDAL

  # fix lib id and Java lib path
  $ install_name_tool -id ogr_MDB.dylib ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib
  $ install_name_tool -change @rpath/libjvm.dylib \
    /Library/Java/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib

  # copy plugin to known GDAL_DRIVER_PATH (sudo needed)
  $ sudo cp -f ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib /Library/Application\ Support/GDAL/1.10/PlugIns/
  ```

*Please post if you have success with this shared plugin method for reading MDB files.*

Comment: thanks for this writeup. I adapted your instructions successfully to enable my locally built libgdal/ogr2ogr to read mdb files. I used this line to compile/link the plugin: `clang++ -Wall -g ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb/ogr*.c* -shared -o ogr_plugins/ogr_MDB.dylib   -Iport -Igcore -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/mdb   -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers  -framework JavaVM .libs/libgdal.a -stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: I just want to give a warning to users unfamiliar with managing qgis's dependencies. By doing this you may break qgis.

Comment: This will not _break_ QGIS. GDAL is merely a dependency. QGIS may not launch if the shared plugin fails to load, and GDAL throws an app-crashing error. To check that the plugin is loading properly, simply issue `ogrinfo --formats` and look for any dylib issues. This is part of Step #5, noted above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simply not using personal geodatabase.  Even Esri dislikes the format, why not just give them shapefiles, kml, gml, geojson...anything but mdb...

Just to back up my Esri dislikes personal geodatabase claim...

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS10and101Deprecation_Plan.pdf

*ArcGIS **Server** 10.1 will no longer support the Microsoft Access based Personal Geodatabase.
With the migration of ArcGIS Server to be 64bit and because of the lack of scalability of Personal Geodatabases, we have removed support for Personal Geodatabases from ArcGIS server 10.1.* [Page 7 of 8, bullet #4]

Comment: My simple reply is that I inherited a huge inventory of data already compiled to personal geodatabase format. I need to make it available to my colleague in a format he can access. I rather suspect this means converting several hundreds of Gb of data back out to say, shapefiles, or KMLs.

The file format itself has limitations but also advantages. Process-wise, for us it is simpler if the software can simply read the data and then move it into a POSTGIS database afterward.

Comment: ahhh...the dreaded legacy data...

Have you seen:
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a non-programmer's answer, but as an end user I have to do what I have to do.

Simply, I installed Lisboa 1.8 and use it to pull out shapefiles from ESRI personal geodatabases. Afterwards, I access them through QGIS Dufour 2.0.

Not a very elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: How do you pull shapefiles out of an .mdb?  Can you elaborate more on this?