# Is there a way to link .MDB to QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, mac, macos, mdb

On requesting shapefiles I've been provided with an .mdb file, which I've never used before.

I don't have Microsoft Access, and am working with QGIS and am on MacOS.

I've researched how I might use this format, but any answers I've looked at reference needing to first install a Microsoft Driver, which is unavailable for mac users.

I also found [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41252/how-to-load-mdb-geodatabases-in-qgis-for-mac?rq=1) which says you can't do it, but it's almost 10 years old so thought I'd ask again, in the hope things had changed!

Does anyone know how I might open this information?

Comment: You can open a MDB file with Power Query in Excel.

Comment: You can't access the Esri geometry in personal geodatabase with Power Query in Excel. Heck, you can't even access it from ArcGIS Pro, so this is a phenomenally bad distribution mechanism, nearly as awful as "It was on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.’" (Douglas Adams)

Comment: I guess you could try to do it using OGR: gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgeo.html and by installing unixODBC drivers on MacOS: https://exploratory.io/note/exploratory/How-to-set-up-ODBC-in-Mac-unixodbc-lQz2Fnp7 . And I suppose better don't do it, ask for the proper format.