# How to get Esri *.gdb file into QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, mac

I have tried the above options, but not being too computer savy, some I didnt get. I tried the homebrew option, but terminal says an error occurs when trying to install. I need this 1 file for a work project.

Comment: Please See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-for-mac-osx-10-6

Comment: Please update your Question with more details like the link @Mapperz provided to explain "the homebrew option" and the exact error message you are seeing.  You have qgis as a tag so including the QGIS version would probably also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

KyngChaos offers its version to include in its GDAL framework, see [New GDAL FileGDB Plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2012/20121122_new_gdal_filegdb_plugin).

The plugin installs **ogr_FileGDB.dylib**. After that, you must download the FileGDB API, because of the Esri's export restrictions, and move 2 .dylib files to /Library/Application Support/GDAL/1.9/Libraries.