# Opening file geodatabase using QGIS for Mac?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, mac, homebrew

I'm trying to open a GDB on QGIS for Mac but having no luck.

Details:

1. I'm currently running OS 10.9.3 on my laptop.
2. I [downloaded and installed QGIS 2.6.1-2 from KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)
3. I installed the GDAL complete package (including NumPy) and the Matplotlib, both from KyngChaos
4. I attempted to follow Ragi Yaser Burhum's udpated Homebrew advice from [this page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-for-mac-osx-10-6). I was successful up through step 3; however, step 4 ("Install gdal using brew...") was not successful for me—perhaps because I had already installed it via the package from KyngChaos?

What should I do from here?

Comment: You need to install the FileGDB_Plugin ([KyngChaos frameworks](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)) with additional requirement (Esri's File GDB API 1.3), see install instructions in the files "VERY IMPORTANT POST-INSTALL.textClipping" or "ReadMe" (in the dmg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I followed your directions; however, I'm still not able to open my GDB via the QGIS Browser (after navigating to it within the directory). Where should I go from here?

Comment: How do you try to open the gdb folder ?

Comment: I navigate within the Browser to the directory where the GDB is located and have attempted to use the drop-down arrow to open its contents. I also have right-clicked the GDB to assess my options. I'm new to QGIS so I may very well be missing an obvious workflow here.

Thanks!

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 4):

You must choose Directory and not File in the dialog:

[image]

Comment: How should I pull up this dialog menu?

Comment: when you want to open a vector layer (Add vector layer), don't choose File but Directory