# ESRI FileGDB driver in QGIS 2.18 for Mac?

Tags: file-geodatabase, mac, qgis-2.18

I recently installed QGIS 2.18.2 from KyngChaos on my personal Macbook, which is running macOS Sierra 10.12.3. However, I am taking a class in which most of the assignments come in the form of geodatabases (.gdb), which my version of QGIS is capable of reading (by opening them via "OpenFileGDB") but not editing. I've found a workaround by converting the feature classes of geodatabases into individual shapefiles on a university computer with ARCCatalog, but I am hoping there is a way to edit these geodatabase files on my own computer. Is there a way for me to install the ESRI FileGDB driver? I followed the instructions in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-for-mac-osx-10-6) , but no luck. Given the version of QGIS and macOS that I have, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

I use Homebrew for my install following the solution provided here https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac.  Make sure to install the Formulae that you need including the filegdb-api, all are listed in the Formula folder.  This method allows me to view and edit a Filegdb.