# Issues Accessing ESRI File Geodatabase within Quantum GIS Desktop

Tags: qgis, shapefile, esri-geodatabase, qgis-plugins

I am trying to access ESRI file gdb from Quantum GIS. I am on Windows 7, 64-bit. I have found many useful threads on how to set up this functionality within Quantum GIS. The method I went for is described in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis) thread. I installed QGIS as part of the OSGeo4W package. I went for an 'Advanced' installation and added QGIS (v.1.8.0) + 'gdal-filegdb:OGR File GDB Driver' library. This has been installed with no issues. In QGIS, when I navigate to 'Add vector layer' window and choose File GDB as source type, I am able to preview contents of the file gdb in the following 'Select vector layers to add' window. Upon making my selection I can see the layer being displayed in table of contents, however  after a short while qgis is crashing. I have attached couple of screenshots of this process:

[image]
[image]

Does anybody have similar experience or else can suggest solution to this issue? 
Do I need the ESRI File Geodatabase API installed as well to be able to access ESRI file GDB?

Many thanks,
Magda

Comment: the ESRI GDB was created in ESRI 9.3, 10 ?

Comment: It was created using v. 10

Comment: Same issue here (and installation procedure). Tried on FileGDB's that were either upgraded to 10.0 from 9.3 or were built from scratch. When adding a layer from the upgraded GDB, QGIS just crashes. You can add a layer from the GDB created from scratch, but doing anything else (panning, zooming, open attribute table) causes QGIS to crash.

Comment: I can not even get to the stage of panning or zooming as it crashes straight after adding a layer in..

Answer (score 1):

As shown under your menu on QGIS: HELP>ABOUT>, what version of GDAL/OGR is your QGIS compiled against?  Is that 1.9.2?

Comment: FileGDB is only working for GDAL 1.9.0 and will probably need to get upgraded for 1.9.2 http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7011

Comment: My QGIS is compiled against v.1.9.2 GDAL/OGR. IS there a way to run QGIS with GDAL 1.9.0 at the moment?

Comment: @SaultDon This issue was closed, cause it's a OSGEO4W-issue http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/309 . This issue was already closed as fixed 8 weeks ago, but from reading it, i can't find a hint what ordinary users can do when still facing problems.