# qgis-bin.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: qgis, convert, error

I'm trying to convert a `.gdb` to `.shp` and I understand this is possible with 3.4. I didn't have any luck with 2.18.

I'm aware this question has come up previously but I have tried the other solutions and they haven't helped.

I am trying to get 3.4 standalone up and running and I continue to get the message/s

> The procedure entry point ... could not be located in the dynamic link
>   library `C:Program Files\QGIS\bin\qwt6.dll.`

Further, three prompts appear asking for `qscintilla2_qt5.dll`, `qca-qt5.dll` and `Qt5Sql.dll.`

I have tried removing all previous traces of 2.18 using regedit. I have installed again as Administrator. I have removed virus software. I have tried copying the various `.dll` files over to the `qgis.exe` directory (btw, I can't see qgis.exe).

[image: prompts]

Comment: All this error widows show broken QGIS installation, not GDB problem. I have no problem to open ESRI qdg files and save them in any supported format in my [NextGIS QGIS 2.18 installation](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/). QGIS uses GDAL gdb driver to open such geodatabases. Can you provide sample data? By the way, I'm developer at NextGIS and GDAL committer.

Comment: As far as I know you have hit a known bug, which should be resolved by a QGIS point release within the next days. You might try QGIS 3.2 standalone in the meantime.

Comment: AndreJ - QGIS 3.2 suffers the same issue Entry Point Not Found.

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov The file is 2.3GB. I've managed to install QGIS 2.18 and I've imported a sample .gdb folder successfully. So it looks like this is actually an issue with the size of the file I'm trying to import and/or some file restriction as mentioned here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49324/how-to-convert-gdb-data-to-shapefiles-without-arcgis

Comment: @Ben10 You may try to use [ogr2ogr](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) as a quick workaround. Not UI way, but may help.

Comment: It turns out there was an issue with the .gdb folder provided by the agency. Once they fixed it I was able to save the required layers as .shp files using QGIS 2.18. @AndreJ, I'll test QGIS 3.4 installation in a week or so to see if the Entry Point Not Found fault is fixed.