# Does the National Hydrology Dataset geodatabase work in qgis?

Tags: file-geodatabase, nhd

I am running QGIS 1.8 on a windows xp pc and trying to put the USGS National Hydrology Dataset ([more info here](http://nhd.usgs.gov/data.html)for Oregon into a project. I try to "add vector data", using directory option then selecting the unzipped folder but it says NHDH_OR_931v210\NHDH_OR.gdb is not a valid data source.

It looks like this was created in ArcGIS 9.2 -- is that the problem?

I am very new to GIS and there may be something very simple I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just curious but do you have GDAL installed (or at least [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/))? If so, you could run [ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) on `NHDH_OR.gdb` as a quick diagnostic. Running this at a command prompt.. `C:\>ogrinfo "C:\PathToData\NHDH_OR.gdb"` ..would tell you every table in the .gdb, if it's not corrupt.

Comment: If you follow the comments on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis you will read that Arcgis 9.x gdb are not supported by QGIS gdal driver. Can anyone confirm that or transform the datasource to Arcgis 10 format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Open your OSGeo4W downloader, select advance setup, and then select `gdal-filegdb` under the libs tree.

There's a step-by-step tutorial here: [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis)

Please note that the FileGDB API Does not support Raster Images.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the tutorial and now when I try to add a vector layer, selecting directory, ESRI fileGDB and click open it says: ...NHDH_OR.gdb is not a valid or recognized data source .

Comment: The NHDH files were created in ArcGIS 9.2 and 9.31. I guess that is why I cannot load them into QGIS. I have utilized the shapefiles instead.