# How do I open the GeoDB files on NaturalEarthData's site without ArcGIS?

Tags: esri-geodatabase

I'm trying to use the admin1 dataset from the NaturalEarthData website. The site offers this data as both shapefiles and GeoDB. The shapefile attribute data is apparently encoded in Windows-1252 and a lot of the characters in some of the attribute data I need are just '?' characters.

The NaturalEarthData site mentions that:

```
The GeoDB format preserves local scripts better than SHP format.
```

I built GDAL against the FileGDB SDK from ArcGIS and verified the GDAL FGDB driver is working correctly using this link:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB

But I can't open files from NaturalEarthData. I always get the following error:

```
Unable to open datasource `ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.gdb' with the following drivers
...
FileGDB
...
```

I don't have access to ArcGIS. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way I can access the GeoDB data?

Comment: Please check following link to download data from Natural Earth Data website (https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog486/l7_p7.html) and go through following link for open .gdb data in qgis (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis) hope it will help you

Comment: Download trial version of ArcGIS for 60 days

Comment: QGIS uses the GDAL driver. If the driver test fails with OGR I doubt it will work with QGIS. Downloading a trial of ArcGIS is only a short term solution.

Comment: If you got really desperate, you could always consider purchasing the $100 ["ArcGIS for Home"](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home)