# Opening Esri fGDB Feature Class in MapInfo Professional 11.0.3

Tags: mapinfo, file-geodatabase

I would like to **open ArcGIS file Geodatabase** feature class and other such fGDB objects **with MapInfo Professional**. NB: converting to Shapefiles or personal mdb is not an acceptable solution. I need it to be seamless and easy for users, just like the ArcSDE and .mdb methods (pictured below).

Any ideas are welcome

[image: MapInfo Open Universal]

Comment: have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/can-mapinfo-professional-use-data-direct-from-a-file-geodatabase

Comment: Ok. So an install of FME on users boxes will add fGDB to the above FME Reader Gallery. The geodatabase API came out years ago. Are there anymore options?

Comment: @GISI, I have just added a new answer to the thread mentioned above. MapInfo Pro 12.5 does support this format out of the box without having to install the full FME