# Installing QGIS with FileGDB?

Tags: qgis, installation, file-geodatabase-api

I need to know how to install QGIS 2.0.1 for Windows 8 64 bit so it can recognize and open ESRI .gdb files.

What do i download and what settings do i change?

I have seen [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis)
but the information at this link was posted two years ago, and I am looking for an update.