# Opening Geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

I received data saved as geodatabase from Esri (10.x) and want to open or work with it in Qgis 2.0.1. The files are like following

[image]

I read a lot in the site about this subject but I still have no idea how it could work.

Can somebody give me step by step advice?

Comment: File or Personal Geodatabase? - In QGIS File GDB is a directory Add Vector Layer DIRECTORY. Personal GDB are file based [OGR]

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83712/how-do-i-install-qgis-with-filegdb/83718#83718