# How to open ArcGIS filegdb in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, file-geodatabase

I have installed OSGeo4W following this: [Installing QGIS with FileGDB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83712/installing-qgis-with-filegdb)

Now I have QGIS Desktop 3.8.3 and gdal-filegdb 2.4.1-1 installed on windows 10.

I open directory that include the following file extensions: gdbindexes, gdbtable, gdbtablx, spx, atx, freelist , selecting ESRI FileGDB as described here too [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis?newreg=47ed2498232141668c609bc359a91ab2)

Error "Invalid data source" is displayed.

How to open these files in QGIS?

Comment: [Windows 10] Layer>Add Layer>Add Vector Layer>Source Type 'Directory' OpenFileDB then go to the folder xxx.gdb and load that in you will get an option to load points, lines, polygons in separate layers

Comment: What actually solved was renaming the folder from myfoldername to myfoldername.gdb

Thank you for this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is the procedure that works:

1. Install QGIS and gdal-filegdb as described here [Installing QGIS with FileGDB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83712/installing-qgis-with-filegdb)
2. Make sure the directory name ending is .gdb (renaming the directory solved the issue in my case)
3. Open the directory as described here [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis?newreg=47ed2498232141668c609bc359a91ab2)
   (in my case it works both selecting type ESRI FileGDB and OpenFileGDB)