# Add file GDB in quantumGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

In QGIS 2.2.0, while adding vector layer, 'ESRI FileGDB' option was missing under Source-Type, refer the attached screenshot.In this case, how can I attach a file GDB in QGIS 2.2.0?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have followed these instructions:

[File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis?rq=1)

you should be able to load the gdb directory (and layer) in the dataset text box.

Comment: Interesting, I've installed QGIS on the machine with ArcGIS installed and haven't done any additional configuration. I have fileGDB option enabled by default. How come?

Comment: @Alex Tereshenkov - Qgis can read the GDB format if only  GDAL/OGR libraries are configurated/compiled to read the GDB API that must be installed and also made available. So I think in your case both things are true.

Comment: yeah, probably these components were installed automatically with ArcGIS Desktop installation. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @MickyInTheSky

I checked your suggestion.

(1) During installation using QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.2.0-1-Setup-x86.exe, there is no such option was available to select/enable gdb components.

(2) After installation, while adding vector layer using the 'source-type' value as 'UK.NTF2' and a fileGDB as dataset, It shows an error message 'Invalid data source'.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: you should use the net installer, as recommended in the link above.http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe