# Extracting data from Geodatabase?

Tags: convert, software-recommendations, esri-geodatabase, file-formats

We have been happily using the 2010 Census Demographic Profile data in Shapefile format for some time. We now want to start using the ACS 5-year Estimates Data Profiles which, sadly, are only available in Geodatabase formats.

What's the best solution?

Do I bite the bullet and buy some version of ArcGIS, are there any services that can convert the files for me or is there some conversion program I can purchase?

Note that I am not a GIS specialist. I've learned enough to do what I want with the 2010 Census demographic shapefiles, but this is not the main focus of my website.

I seek recommendations and advice.

Comment: Which software are you using so far?

Comment: Is this data in File Geodatabase (*.gdb) or Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) format?

Comment: If your data is in file geodatabase format, you might try [GDB Flee](http://gdbflee-mweisman.rhcloud.com/) to convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider two options:

1. Get ArcGIS Explorer.  It is a lightweight ESRI GIS Viewer and offered for free.  Since it is by ESRI, you will get file geodatabase support.  I don't have much experience with it, but it should offer the ability to export the data in another format.http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer
2. Get QGIS, an open source and powerful product and install an add-on for .gdb support.  Here is the article:
   [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis)

ArcGIS Explorer might be the easiest and offer the best support for .gdb... since it is an ESRI technology.

Comment: Can anybody confirm that Explorer lets you export data to a different format?