# Can FileGDB SDK be made to support custom coordinate systems?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

In May 2012, a question was asked about [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

In the comments there, it was pointed out by @MattWilkie that the FileGDB SDK does not support custom coordinate systems.

Has there been a workaround developed for custom coordinate systems?

Comment: Adding custom projection support is on the FGDB API 1.4 enhancement list, but the final feature list has not been announced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternative GDAL driver "OpenFileGDB" which supports also other projections http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html.

Comment: Note that GDAL 1.11 or higher is required to use this, which may not be the default yet when installing from OSGeo4w.