# qgis 2.8.1 arcgis filegdb incomplete list in win-version

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

i am running qgis 2.8.1 (OSGeo4W 64bit-version) on mac (10.10.3) and win (7)

... and was just recently confronted with different behavior of both versions when trying to open (ESRIs) file.gdb. 
the following img shows the FeatureClass listing in ArcCatalog (see the two polygon FCs at the end)

[image: esri/arc catalog - gdb feature class list]

this img shows the "add vector layer / directory / ESRI FileGDB" result on mac: 
[image: open fileGDB on mac os]

and tho following one the corresponding result on Win7 
[image: open fileGDB on WIN7]

on win7 one table and the point featureclass are displayed properly 

.

Why are the polygon feature classes missing?

Comment: ... just found some reasonable clues about that phenomenon: see the comment in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis.