# Where can I find a binary ogr_FileGDB.dll compilled for Windows?

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase-api

Need GDAL 2.0 with support FileGDB driver. The GDAL build from http://gisinternals.com does not contain this driver.

Comment: If you are OK using the development version, currenlty GDAL 2.1, which has a OpenFileGDB driver see http://gisinternals.com/development.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis). Or you could download FileGDB API directly from ESRI [here](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/).