# Cannot save as ESRI FileGDB in QGIS?

Tags: file-geodatabase, qgis-2

In QGIS v2.6, I was able to save a vector layer as ESRI FileGDB. However, in v2.8 and v2.10 this no longer seems available.

Am I missing something?

Or why is this no longer available in the standard installation for Windows?

Comment: It depends on what driver you are using as to whether you can read or write to a FGDB.  This answer may shed some light:  [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis/26301#26301)

Comment: My company's IT department is happy to install QGIS from a standard installation, but they wouldn't go into such advanced installation instructions. Secondly when I tick QGIS and the FileGDB lib, it tries to install a whole bunch of dependent libs, and then halfway through it falls over telling me the download is incomplete. Is there any way I can install just this FGDB lib after I have fully installed QGIS 2.10 the normal way?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read, edit and create features of a FileGDB in QGIS 3 (maybe also QGIS 2). For Windows you need an OSGeo4W-Installation with the optional FileGDB-Driver (not OpenFileGDB).