# Need File Geodatabase (*.gdb) read/write support in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, boundless-suite, osgeo

I have followed the instructions shown in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis) but still don't have the ESRI FileGDB option only the Open File GDB. In my case, I am in the most current QGIS version - Lyon (2.12.0).

[image]

[image]

OSGeo4w shell Results:
[image]

Comment: ESRI FileGDB & OpenFileGDB are the same thing, you will not get full File Geodatabase support without ArcObjects installed on the same machine and this extended version has to be licensed by ESRI. The same goes with other software (FME is the same) in this case has Openfile GDB API and FileGDB (ArcObjects) the latter must been installed and licensed see the matrix tables https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Notes-on-FME-and-ESRI-Versions-and-Compatibility)

Comment: There is a tangible difference between ArcObjects, the Esri File Geodatabase API, and the Open FileGDB libraries.  I know FME can use core ArcGIS libraries, but I thought QGIS was limited to a choice between the Esri and Open file geodatabases libraries (the latter being open-source, reverse-engineered (and read-only) and the former being provided as a library by Esri (and read-write, except for complex feature classes))

Comment: Do you have OSGeo4w shell? If so please post the results of the following command which will verify which drivers you have installed: ogrinfo --formats

Comment: I added the results as part of the thread info

Comment: Had a funny exprnce then when it failed to connect the first time but did on the second.

Answer (score 4):

I see this:

[image]

and my options in the OSGeo4W Setup ('advanced install') that are probably relevant were:

[image]

Comment: so this really works??

Comment: It Works For Me(tm). Select "Directory" in that "Add vector layer" dialog box, set the Source/Type to "ESRI FileGDB", click the "Browse" button to get the "Open Directory" dialog, browse to the directory that is the FileGDB, and choose which feature classes to add as layer(s), voila. QGIS 2.12.0