# What is difference between version 2.10 & 2.14 in FileGDB driver support in QGIS? GDB version is 10.2.2

Tags: esri-geodatabase, qgis-2.14

Problem is with QGIS Desktop 2.14.0.
 I need to edit a FileGDB in QGIS.

I have followed the instructions shown in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis) and have added the option "ESRI FileGDB".

[image: esrifileGBD]

But after I choose the folder and press open there is an error: `"Invalid Data Source" ... is not a valid or recognized data source`
.

The same error is encountered when I try to open a File GDB with Type OpenFileGDB.

But when I don't use OSGeo4W, and try to open the GBD with standard QGIS Desktop 2.14.0, there is no problem. The GDB is opened in read-only mode.

What is the problem? How can I edit features in a File GDB in QGIS?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of the source file geodatabases.  The Esri FileGDB driver only supports v10.0 and higher file geodatabases.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26301/25417