# ArcGIS Personal Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, personal-geodatabase

I'm working with a lot of shapes and raster files in one map document (.mxd) in ArcMap and I would like to send the project to another person that works with me.

I would like to know if there is a way to add all files from a map document to a geodatabase, and if map packages can be opened in other GIS software packages, such as QGIS.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, map packages (MPKs) can only be opened with ArcGIS software. However the contents inside them (fgdb for example) can be opened with many different software packages.

Answer (score 5):

I would choose a file geodatabase instead of a personal geodatabase.  It can be [used by QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26301/59).

I would put everything under a common parent folder and set the "store pathnames" checkbox in the mxd before saving it.  (File>Map Document Properties...).

Zip up the parent folder and send to other users.