# Link Geodatabase to GeoTiff on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, file-geodatabase, ubuntu

I downloaded gridded soils data from gSSURGO and used ArcGIS to export the raster to a GeoTiff of keys for use on Linux.  On my Ubuntu machine, I have imported the GeoTiff to QGIS as a raster layer, and have imported the geodatabase table as a vector, using the instructions here [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis), but they are still separate from one another.

How do I connect the GeoTiff with the geodatabase so that I can visualize values from the geodatabase?