# Adding SQLite layers to ArcGIS Pro throws error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041538"

Tags: arcgis-pro, sqlite

I have a SQLite database which I have just created in QGIS and I want to open it in ArcGIS Pro.

In Catalog I have added the database to the project but when I try to add layers to the map I get the error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041538".

I want to have a common source of data for QGIS and ArcGIS Pro if possible so using a different format is not ideal.

Comment: GeoPackage (also a SQLite database) will probably work better as a common format.

Comment: @user30184 - Can you expand on why that is?

Comment: Clarify first what do you exactly mean by SQLite database. Do you mean SQLite with Spatialite geometries?

Comment: Yes. Data which I exported from QGIS as Spatialite.

Comment: If your goal is just to have a common data-source between ArcMap and QGIS you may have more luck by using a file geodatabase (ESRI product will obviously work  well with it and you can enable QGIS  to have read/write capability by installing the ESRI FileGDB driver,for more read this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis/26301#26301

Answer (score 0):

SQL Lite is supported in ArcGIS Pro by creating a connection to a folder and viewing it through the Folder node. (Not by creating a database connection as you've said you've done). You will interact with it much like you would a file geodatabase (fgdb)

Reference:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/databases/work-with-sqlite-databases-in-arcgis-pro.htm

Comment: Since I do not yet have the reputation to comment - but the issue endures: The solution posited by @KHibma does not work. The issue experienced by OP manifests itself with large datasets (several million rows +). The issue tends to also occur with datasets generated from QGIS, including the most recent 3.10, and ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that I am experiencing this issue.
I have a geopackage database, which has a table inside it, containing no geometry.
Attempting to add this table into ArcGIS Pro, either using the Database/file navigation method fails.

The only difference is that i receive a slightly different error code.
Exception from HRESULT:0x8004152F

I can add other tables from that database, but no the non-geometry table. Am using ArcGIS pro 2.4

Comment: I got this same error (HRESULT:0x8004152F) in Pro 2.4. When I tried loading the file using Pro 2.6 it warned of an unknown coordinate system, but otherwise loaded fine. Sounds like the lack of a coordinate system is why you're having problems loading the non-geometry table, but that Pro 2.6 might be a solution.