# GeoDatabase (GDB) import not working (QGIS3)

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, import

I have a *.gdb which I normaly could load in QGIS version (3.4 / 3.8) following that instructions (or symply drag'n'dop): [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

But it returns a error: Invalid Data Source: [...] is not a valid or recognized data source.

[image]

I also tryed ogr2ogr to translate it first in to shapefiles:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ./shp ./Schoeningstedt.gdb
```

With no result. 
Whats wrong? Could anyone test my gdb? You can download it here: [www.map-site.de/tmp/Schoeningstedt.gdb.zip](https://www.map-site.de/tmp/Schoeningstedt.gdb.zip)

Comment: not working for me either... can you confirm this works in ArcGIS? I can load other GDB's no problem, but this one doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't have a own installation of ArcGIS but my client is telling me that it is working fine

Comment: your database only contains rasters 'dgm1_32583_5930, diff_map1_circ15_32583_930 etc) that is not supported by the OpenFIleGDB (as esri locked it out of the Open Geodatabase API) see bottom of https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/data-management/file-geodatabase-api-details/

Comment: Maybe you can have your client export them from ArcGIS to a format you can work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By opening a few of the biggest datafiles (.gbdtable) with a text editor I can see in the header lines texts like "rasterband_id", "rrd_factor", and "block_data". I guess that this geodatabase contains only rasterdata and therefore ogrinfo that runs with success does not find any layers.

```
ogrinfo Schoeningstedt.gdb
INFO: Open of `Schoeningstedt.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
```

An old ticket about adding raster support into OpenFileGDB driver is at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7008.

Answer (score 1):

The geodatabase contains a raster dataset and Qgis is not able to open those.[image: raster dataset]

Comment: confirmed as in comments