# Invalid data source error in QGIS while reading .gdb file

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

ftp://ftpdata.dnr.sc.gov/gisdata/elev/DEM/

Above is the link to the FTP site provided by SCDNR. It is free data provided by the State of South Carolina. I downloaded the Horrydem and attempted to import it into QGIS but I continue to get the `invalid data source` error message.

All of the files should be the same. If you're able to import it into QGIS, please let me know how you did it. I've attempted both the vector import command and "drag and drop" as I've seen others mention. None have worked.

Comment: Have a look at this post about importing GDB files into QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

Raster data stored in File Geodatabases is currently not supported by GDAL/QGIS. There is work being done by Nyall Dawson and North Road along with members of the GDAL development community to hopefully bring this feature to light in the upcoming time.

Watch this page for news regarding the development of the raster driver:
https://north-road.com/blog/

Comment: See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/173