# Cannot open Esri Geodatabase files on QGIS 3.12 and 3.13 on MacOS Catalina

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api, macos

I've been struggling for the last two days to get QGIS 3.12 running on macOS Catalina to open ESRI Geodatabase (GDB) files. I've tried using OpenFileGDB with no luck - I just get the following error "Invalid Data Source: /Users/xxxx/Documents/GIS/1. Geology/Australia/National/1M Geology - SHP/geodatabase/geology_1M.gdb is not a valid or recognized data source." I've tried with multiple different GDB files with the same error message.
I've also tried Mark Egge's solution for Mojave [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis) with no success - Steps 1-3 work ok but when I run `ogrinfo --formats` FileGDB doesn't appear.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Download some .gdb from the GDAL test suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/autotest/ogr/data/filegdb. Does your QGIS open them with the OpenFileGDB driver?

Comment: I downloaded them and my QGIs opens them all with no issue

Comment: It probably means that your geodatabases are somehow different but without a sample it is hard to say in which way. I believe that compressed geodatabases are not supported nor geodatabases with raster data.

Comment: After some digging, it looks like the Geodatabase are compressed - thanks for the pointer.