# ESRI FileGDB - QGIS 3.12 vs 3.14

Tags: file-geodatabase

On my one laptop, I have 3.12.2 installed, on the other 3.14.15. In 3.12.2, I can see ESRI FileGDB as a type in the directory, in 3.14.15, this option is not there. Panicking a bit, as relying on being able to open ESRI GDB's for teaching purposes next week, but with 3.14.15 installed, students will not be open the data supplied!

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26285/29431)?

Comment: I have both QGIS 3.10.9 and QGIS 3.14.15 and both have FileGDB installed. Try to reinstall QGIS using OSGeo4w installation, as Kadir Şahbaz said. It may solve the problem.

Comment: I too am facing the same problem. Under the Select packages window of OSGEO4W installer, the ESRI FileGDB does not list. Even after unchecking the 'Hide obselete' checkbox, still ESRI FileGDB does not list.
Wonder if there is an issue in packaging (or licensing the driver, hope not!). I checked install with all 4 download sites.