# Can I export QGIS tool results to anything other than a shapefile or DBF?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use the QGIS 'Split Lines at Points' tool, since my organization does not have the package to unlock the ESRI version of the tool. I am able to access my data in an enterprise ESRI Geodatabase just fine, however the only outputs listed for that tool are shapefile and dbf. We use feature classes in our database organization, and my supervisor is wary of converting the data from a shapefile back to a feature class. Is there any plugin I can add to QGIS to allow the tools to output the data to feature classes?

Comment: geopackage? https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/data-management/how-to-use-ogc-geopackages-in-arcgis-pro/

Answer (score 7):

QGIS can read **and** write to File Geodatabases.  Reading FGDBs is achieved with the default QGIS install (and has been for several years).  Writing to a FGDB requires an OSGeo4W64 install and selecting the appropriate library.  The procedure for doing this custom install is pretty easy, and is covered well in an answer provided by the SE GIS user *Get Spatial* at [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis/26301#26301)

Answer (score 4):

When you run Split Lines at Points leave the output as the default temporary file and leave "Open output file after running algorithm" checked. When it's done, Export the new temporary layer as whatever you want - shapefile, geopackage, etc. I don't believe you can export to an ESRI Geodatabase, however.

I curious why your supervisor is wary of importing a feature class in the geodatabase. Seems like a pretty routine operation to me. If you're having problems with imports then something seems amiss.