# How view or query this DEM dataset

Tags: dem

All I want to do is get accurate elevation data, so that I can compare short but very steep hills to pedal up on bicycle.

I start here and see this 2018 DEM:

Lidar-Topo
2018 PA Luzerne County Lidar

Point Spacing: 0.35 m

Alternate Name: USGS: PA_LuzerneCounty_2018

[COAST-NOAA](https://coast.noaa.gov/inventory/#search=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)  at -75.8924, 41.2489

I don't see any JSON file that I can download and manually query to get point elevation. Maybe that is linked in the metadata.

So maybe I need to download a viewer. I tried ArcGISExplorer, but Win10 won't even try to install that. I tried Manifold but that doesn't help, it needs map files.

ArcGIS online viewer only seems to give a shaded map: https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?featurecollection=https%3A%2F%2Fimagery.pasda.psu.edu%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2Fpasda%2FUSGS_Luzerne_DEM_2018%2FMapServer%3Ff%3Djson%26option%3Dfootprints&supportsProjection=true&supportsJSONP=true

This next one gives me a 404 not found error (the rockyftp host does not exist) for the viewer or download: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/usgs-ned-pa-luzerne-county-pa-2019-1ft

Finally, https://maps.equatorstudios.com/ is a nice online interface, but it only seems to use low-res 2006 data, which also has some major flaws.

(The county website is no help. Penn State shows a dark, opaque shaded overlay: https://maps.psiee.psu.edu/preview/map.ashx?layer=1821  with no elevation data.)

How do I view the 2018 dataset in 2D, or at least query it by co-ordinates?

======edited as per BERA's comment===========

At the COAST-NOOA link posted above, in the upper right is a click-to-download, which gives the popup:

> Download all United States Interagency Elevation Inventory topographic, topobathy, and bathymetric lidar, and IfSAR data set footprints and attribute information in Esri gdb and Open Geospatial Consortium GeoPackage formats.
> Download Esri Geodatabase (estimated 52 MB)
> Download OGC GeoPackage (estimated 173 MB)

I had downloaded the [gdb zip](https://coast.noaa.gov/inventory/api/usiei_gdb.zip) yesterday, which contains a large number of various files (atx, indexes and so on).

Can I just drag all those files onto QGIS, as discussed--> [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

Comment: Can you add a link to the site where the 0.35 DEM can be downloaded? I would be surprised if you cant use QGIS to see and query the DEM

Comment: Ty, @BERA. I edited my post. Would you suggest the gdb or ogc?

Comment: @Bob White, for serious Luzerne County elevation data, try https://www.pasda.psu.edu/download/usgs/Luzerne_County_WVSA_LiDAR2017/Bare_Earth_1ft_DEM/ or https://www.pasda.psu.edu/download/usgs/Luzerne_County_WVSA_LiDAR2017/Bare_Earth_1m_DEM/

Comment: Thanks @Pointdump. I did have the data, but don't know how to search or interpret it.