# Exporting shapefile to Esri file geodatabase in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, file-geodatabase

Is it possible to export a shapefile as a file geodatabase in QGIS?

I have been trying to do so, but its not giving me the options in the format dropdown box when I 'save as' the shapefile.

[image]

Comment: https://north-road.com/2022/11/24/qgis-3-28-improvements-for-working-with-esri-formats-and-services/

Comment: The GDAL driver can write as well now https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html. QGIS has been missing the UI for that until now as BERA linked.

Comment: A feature class exported into a file geodatabase is not a "file" but a "table".

Answer (score 4):

ESRI's file Geodatabase is a proprietary format, and the basic installation of QGIS only reads file Geodatabases, it does not write to them. The question [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis) has an answer (from user @Get Spatial) that goes into detail about how the Open FileGDB driver can be installed to enable write access.