# Accessing File Geodatabase Files without ArcMap

Tags: file-geodatabase

I was working on a project last night on ArcMap but the license provided by my university expired. I was using a local ArcGIS toolbox to process some data to get the local getis ord and local moran's I. All the outputs were stored in a file geodatabase. However, I only need the results and the only way I know how to access them is by clicking the results under geoprocessing.

Is there any other way to access the results without ArcMap?

Comment: As far as I know, QGIS supports the File Geodatabase format. Haven't tried it myself though. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis

Comment: QGIS can read the data. You can also use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) to convert the data to many open formats, for example geopackage. This will convert all tables in a fgdb to a geopackage `ogr2ogr C:\folder\converted_data.gpkg C:\folder\yourfilegeodatabase.fgdb`