# Use geodatabase (GDB) file in Extract/Clip by Extent tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, file-geodatabase

I want to run Extract/Clip by Extent tool on a file geodatabase (GDB), without opening it in QGIS (3.30.1).

However, when I open up the interface, and select "Select file...", there's no option to select a directory, only a file.

[image]

I've reviewed the questions and answers of how to load GDB files into QGIS, typically using the Add Vector Layer... interface:

eg [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

However, they don't appear to answer how to use a GDB file within (say) a processing tool.

Answer (score 2):

At last in recent QGIS version, clicking on the three dot next to the wrench icon will let you choose between "Select File..." and "Browse for Layer...". You need to choose the right option depending on you data format.

- For file based data format (like shapefile for exemple) you could use the "Select File..." option.
- For data in a database format (like a file database or geopackage) you will need to use the "Browse for Layer..." option to navigate to the layer located inside the database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As well as navigating using the *Browse for Layer...* dialog, you can also use the Browser pane to navigate to the layer within the GDB file/folder in your file system, and drag-and-drop the layer into the Processing Tool.

[image]

Result:

[image]