# How to write more than one layer to an existing file geodatabase

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

**Background:**

At 3.28.10 I have installed the ESRI FileGDB driver, [using the advanced OSGEO4W install](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis).  This allows me to write a vector layer to a **new** ESRI File Geodatabase (FGDB), using *Export > Save Features As*...

However, I am unable to write any additional layers to an **existing** FGDB because the Export dialog box does not allow me to enter the name of an existing FGDB.  As a result, I am only able to create new FGDBs that contain just a single layer.

The Export dialog window has two options for saving to a FGDB, as shown in the screenshot:
*ESRI File Geodatabase

ESRI FileGDB*

Selecting either option results in the same single-layer FGDB output.

[image]

**Question:**

How to export additional layers to an existing File Geodatabase?

Comment: Slightly off topic -- but you shouldn't install the filegdb driver on newer qgis versions. The out of the box install comes with the full featured openfilegdb driver, which has full support now for editing and creating gdbs and none of the issues of the filegdb driver!

Comment: XLNT!  That's good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Export - Save Features As... has probably a bug in the file selector. It really does not allow to select an existing file geodatabase. Maybe it is because the gdb is actually a directory, not a file.

As a workaround I managed to add layers into an existing gdb by writing the name of the gdb from the keyboard.

[image]

```
ogrinfo layers.gdb
INFO: Open of `layers.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
Layer: new_scratch_layer (Multi Polygon)
Layer: new_scratch_layer2 (Multi Polygon)
```

Comment: Alternatively to typing it you could select the file gdb folder in the file selector, copy the path in the address bar hit cancel then paste in the right box. This way you don't need to remember long path...

Comment: I've submitted a bug report at: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54566