# How to open a file geodatabase with tables and relationships in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

How can I open or connect to an ESRI file geodatabase in QGIS? I don't want to only see the features (shapes), I want to make sure that tables and relationships are opened correctly, too.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Can you expand on your question, what do you mean by connect?  Do you have ArcGIS software?  ArcCatalog may be used to view geodatabase contents.

Comment: Hi,I would like to use open source QGIS to open filegoedatabase but not only the shapes.Tables and the relationships too

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22201/how-to-access-file-geodatabase-in-qgis. @Juan Guerra, please see the accepted answer in that question.

Comment: GDAL has no concept of relationship classes, so you cannot "open simple relationships" with any open source package. Perhaps we could add something to open attributed relationship classes since they do have a table associated with them, but it currently doesn't do that.

Comment: Thak very much for your reply.I would like to see at least the tables of my geodabase and not only the shapes.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking for QGIS 3.0, yes, you can open/connect/view all of these. You can view the structure within the "Browser" and add anything directly to your map, tables and layers alike.