# Writing data into Esri *.mdb personal geodatabase using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, personal-geodatabase

I have an empty *.mdb database that I have to fill with data.

The problem is that I cannot install ArcGIS for Desktop on Ubuntu, so I decided to do it using QGIS 2.0.1 with a Grass plugin.

However, I do not know how to import data into *.mdb using it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I don't believe it's possible to write to an Esri personal geodatabase (*.mdb) using non-Esri software like QGIS. As far as I know, read-only access is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS would most likely be relying on the GDAL driver for Personal Geodatabases support which currently only supports read capability (so no creation or writing to one).

You can see some info on the PGeo driver at http://gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html

Answer (score -1):

I think even ESRI would recommend staying away from the .mdb-based personal geodatabase and instead use the File Geodatabase, and in that case you can use QGIS for that:

[File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

[How to access file geodatabase in Qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22201/how-to-access-file-geodatabase-in-qgis)